# Does the admin of a public Facebook page know who hides another person's comment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-comments

When a person does not like another person's comment on a public Facebook page, I suppose the best thing he/she can do is to hide that comment. But when he/she presses the hide link, will this information be notified to the admin? Or can the admin have any way to check who hides the comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not be notified to the admin. And there is no official way to check who hides the comment. When he/she hides a comment, it is just hidden from his/her view, others can still see it. Comment will be visible to the person who wrote it and their friends.